# how do you assign the inner array values to a variable in php

Tags: php

I have an associative array in php. 
the content of associative array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 50074494
            [4] => 25013372
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 474
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 985
            [12] => 34951
            [13] => 18143
            [14] => 4
            [15] => 2
            [16] => 94
            [17] => 1
            [18] => 1.26
            [19] => 7.9
            [20] => 2013-06-27 10:19:21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 50078122
            [4] => 25000164
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 463
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 860
            [12] => 28290
            [13] => 16944
            [14] => 4
            [15] => 1
            [16] => 94
            [17] => 1
            [18] => 1.13
            [19] => 7.1
            [20] => 2013-06-27 10:19:51
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 50078630
            [4] => 24995538
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 155
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 616
            [12] => 23203
            [13] => 4892
            [14] => 3
            [15] => 1
            [16] => 95
            [17] => 0
            [18] => 1.04
            [19] => 6.5
            [20] => 2013-06-27 10:20:21
        )

)
```

I would like to be able to assign the inner array values to a variable. I need variable to look like this:

```
    echo $variable 
    3 1 0 50074494 25013372 2  474 .. 2013-06-27 10:19:21
   .
   .
```

I have this code so far:

```
$variable;
foreach ($lines as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($value as &$val) 
    {

        $variable=$variable . $val . ' ';

    }
    echo $variable;
echo "\n";
}
```

with this code it looks like I am getting 3 times of variable. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Please post the output of your `var_dump($lines)` array.

Comment: have a look at the extract php function?

Comment: Reset `$variable` at the begining of the first `foreach`. Like, `foreach ($lines as $key => $value) { $variable = ''; //and then your code`. Anyway, if you want to just implode (i.e. not iterate all the values and perform some complex operations on them) values with spaces, use @Travesty3 solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array, and you want to store the values in a space-separated string, you could do this:

```
$string = implode(' ', $array);
echo $string;
```

So your loop might look like this:

```
foreach ($lines as $value) {
    $value[20] = '"'. $value[20] .'"'; // from comments
    echo implode(' ', $value) ."\n";
}
```

Comment: @Traversty3, thank you. This is great. One other quick question. Since the last value ($value[20]) is a time stamp, I need to insert double quotes around this value. How could I do this?

Comment: I would just do `$value[20] = '"'. $value[20] .'"';` on the line before the `implode`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of implode instead of foreach. Also, it doesn't seem like you need the value of `$key`:

```
foreach ($lines as $value) {
    echo implode(" ", $value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Also, I'm not sure I quite understood your question? What do you mean by "3 times of variable"?